# Grafana 10.2.2 Windows OSS build Dashboard By Geo Map

Tags: grafana

While i using Grafana 10.2.2 windows oss build to ploat a Geomap using Infinity as data base via API call , format as time series the API called values will be comes table view but in geo map no data shown why?

Please help to plot Geo map correctly in Grafana 10.2.2 windows oss build via API Call